# IOS Swift - how to find multiple views with common attribute

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift, uiview, classname

Looking for a way to get multiple views with a common String attribute, for now I wrote the following method to get a collection of UIViews by their tag:

```
extension UIView {
func getViewsByTag(tag:Int) -> Array<UIView?>{
    var views = Array<UIView?>()

    for view in self.subviews{
        if view.subviews.count > 0{
            views.extend((view as UIView).getViewsByTag(tag))
        }

        if view.tag == tag {
            println(view.tag)
            views.append(view as? UIView)
        }
    }
    return views
}
}
```

However it would be better if the input would be a String with a meaning, for example "required" to represent all required fields in a form.

**Q**:Is there a String property that can be used for that manner, or is there a better way to get a collection of views in swift?

Answer (score 6):

You could alternatively use the `identifier` property.

```
extension UIView {
  func getViewsByTag(tag:Int) -> Array<UIView?>{
    return subviews.filter { ($0 as UIView).tag == tag } as [UIView]
  }
  func getViewsByIdentifier(id:String) -> Array<UIView?>{
    return subviews.filter { ($0 as UIView).identifier == id } as [UIView]
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that identifier a unique property, so it cannot be used for this purpose

Comment: One more thing, this method only iterates the first level of the view hierarchy.

Comment: what @shlomi said, note: `viewWithTag()` returns the first view in the (entire) hierarchy–traversal type not documented–and it's very common to group views for layout purposes

Comment: Actually I'm out of bussiness here. So I can't comment really. Still, people seem to find it helpful the one or other way...